# How to define ManyToManyField in Django for tests

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

To test my serializers in Django rest framework I use `create()` method to create fields. But I can't create ManyToManyField.

Guess, firstly I need to create objects for first model and for second model otherwise ManyToManyField bound can't be created. But still can't define ManyToManyField for test with create method.

Please help me to realize how it should work correctly. I've read Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), but haven't got how to solve my issue.

Here is my code example:

`models.py`

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='my_books')
    readers = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='UserBookRelation', related_name='books')
```

`test.py`

```py
class BookSerializerTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = User.objects.create(username='test_username')
        self.book_1 = Book.objects.create(name='Test book 1', price=750, author_name='Author 1', owner=self.user)
        self.book_2 = Book.objects.create(name='Test book 2', price=650, author_name='Author 1', owner=self.user)

    def test_readers(self):
        users = [self.user]
        reader = self.book_1.readers.set(users)
        print(f'Readers: {reader}')
```

`readers` is `None`, how to define `self.user`?

Comment: Try to print `self.book_1.readers.all()` and see what happens. Currently you are printing the result of `set()` which is nothing

Comment: Where did you print `readers`?

Comment: Thank you, @BrianDestura , that is correct. Now I get that it is QuerySet and I need get it like QuerySet.

Comment: @DavidLu, thank you for your time, when I tried to print `self.book_1.readers` I got `None`. Now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the command is correct. You can define `ManyToMany` using set and modify using `add`, `remove`.
You can also use just ids of them like the following.

```
self.book_1.readers.set([self.user.id])
self.book_1.readers.add(1)
self.book_1.readers.remove(1)
```